импортирую библиотеку tkinter и вылетает ошибка
import tkinter
win = tkinter.Tk()
win.mainloop()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1\PycharmProjects\Torrent_helperR\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    win = tkinter.Tk()
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2459, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    C:/Users/1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/Torrent_helperR/.venv/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/Torrent_helperR/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/Torrent_helperR/.venv/library C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/Torrent_helperR/library C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/Torrent_helperR/tcl8.6.14/library C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/tcl8.6.14/library



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.


Process finished with exit code 1


Ну это Python. где-то работает, где-то не работает. Попробуй запустить через различные способы: терминал твоего IDE, командную строку, powershell, git bash (если есть) и т.д.

через командную строку работает, а вот через пайчарм нет

Установите Python 3.12 или ждите пока выйдет Python 3.13.1, где эта проблема исправлена.

Python 3.13.0 уж этот код как-нибудь выполнит. При установке самого Питона надо проследить чтоб была НЕ включена опция "Download free-threaded binaries (experimental". Я создал тему после выхода версии 3.13.0, где можно было бы отслеживать подобные глюки, но её быстренько удалили - "незначимая" понимаете ли. Вот теперь периодически читаем это. А писатели Питона меж тем размышляют, о вечном наверное. Скорость размышлений поистине "впечатляющая".
